# upload this file from the client side to the server side on an intranet using JavaScript and PHP - undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php

How do I upload this file from the client side to the server side on an intranet using JavaScript and PHP?

Why do I get this error?

> Undefined index: file_data

in `file_handler.php` relating to:

```
$fd = $_POST['file_data'];
```

My `Uploader.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <title>Upload file</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "file_handler.php";
        var file_data = "name=s:\a.pdf&size=123&other=etc";
        http.open("POST", url, true);

        // headers
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", file_data.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(file_data);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My file_handler.php page is:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    
    // file data
    $fd = $_POST['file_data'];

    // working on the file
    $temp_dir = 'sub3/';
    $new_dir = 'sub5/';

    // new unique name
    $new_name = time() . '_' . $fd['name'];

    // copy?
    if (@move_uploaded_file($temp_dir . $fd['name'], $new_dir . $new_name)) {
        unlink($temp_dir . $fd['name']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`file_data` is not `$_POST` data. Your requesting `$_POST` data are `name`, `size` & `other`. Try this instead.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    // working on the file
    $temp_dir = 'sub3/';
    $new_dir = 'sub5/';
    // new unique name
    $new_name = time() . '_' . $_POST['name'];

    // copy?
    if (@move_uploaded_file($temp_dir . $_POST['name'], $new_dir . $new_name)) {
        unlink($temp_dir . $_POST['name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mehedi, unfortunately that did not work. There is something I am still missing. php returns the name, i.e. s:\a.pdf, which makes sense. Somehow I need to create the "file_data" that an <input type="file" does.